# How do I use attribute_mapped_collection with a defaultdict(list)?

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy, defaultdict

I am trying to use an `attribute_mapped_collection` that maps the attribute to a list of the objects with that attribute.

To explain this better, in Python, I can implement this like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
```

Every time I append to a specific key, it simply creates a list that collects
the items with the same key. So we get

```
[ins] In [18]: my_dict = defaultdict(list)

[ins] In [19]: my_dict[1].append(1)

[nav] In [20]: my_dict[1].append(2)

[ins] In [21]: my_dict
Out[21]: defaultdict(list, {1: [1, 2]})
```

This would be incredibly useful in sqlalchemy in the following circumstance:

```
class Node(Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class Attribute(Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    node_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('node.id'))
    node = db.relationship(
        'Node',
        backref=backref('attributes', collection_class='attribute_mapped_collection('node_attr')))

    node_attr = db.Column(db.String) # a string based keyword-attribute
```

This works fantastically *if all the `attributes` have unique `node_attr`'s*. As soon as we have repeats we run into dictionary keys defined by the last matching `node_attr`. Every successive value with the same key clobbers the previous value.

I would like for the mapped dictionary `Node.attributes` to be a dictionary of attributes mapped to lists of the objects like in the above defaultdict example. How can I do this?

I am trying to comb through the documentation to find a simple way to use a
`defaultdict(list)` instead of a builtin `dict` but it looks like I might have to [implement a special `MappedCollection` class](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#custom-dictionary-based-collections). Unfortunately, the documentation for this is extremely confusing, and I am not at all sure which magic methods I really have to implement. For example, in the linked section I see this:

```
@collection.internally_instrumented
def __setitem__(self, key, value, _sa_initiator=None):
    # do something with key, value
    super(MyMappedCollection, self).__setitem__(key, value, _sa_initiator)

@collection.internally_instrumented
def __delitem__(self, key, _sa_initiator=None):
    # do something with key
    super(MyMappedCollection, self).__delitem__(key, _sa_initiator)
```

But I have no idea what `_sa_initiator` is. Furthermore, the documentation
specifies:

```
class sqlalchemy.orm.collections.MappedCollection(keyfunc)¶

  Bases: builtins.dict
```

Which implies the `MappedCollection` is already based on the `builtin.dict` and therefore can't be overriden for my use case.

Guidance in this direction, if this is the direction I have to go, would be much appreciated.

### Update

I have begun cheating with a workaround.

Using the [orm.reconstructor](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html?highlight=reconstructor#sqlalchemy.orm.reconstructor) I am simply creating the defaultdict on the object's load. I don't think this will cause any performance issues, as the actual set of values is rather small, generally speaking, but if there is a way to do this with SQLA, I would greatly like to know it.